# How to only have one instance of a Dagger @subcomponent?

Tags: kotlin, dagger

For other dependencies I can use a @scope such as @Singleton to make it only have one instance.

For example:

```
@Component
@Singleton
interface ApplicationComponent {

    fun getMySingleInstanceDependency(): MySingleInstanceDependency
}

@Singleton
class MySingleInstanceDependency @Inject constructor()
```

If I add a @subcomponent to the main component, it returns a new instance every time I require an instance. The only thing I can think of is to use the @Component.Builder to pass an instance of the subcomponent inside so it uses the same instance every time, but that doesn't sound right. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about different question. Lifecycle of object instance should nothing to do with `subcomponent`. Let me explain here your question.

1. By default all dependencies are created with your `provide` annotation. Which would be called each time we are requesting this item in different Dagger `modules`. **Unless** this particular dependency is annotated as `singleton`.
2. You subcomponent should nothing to do with above allocation. 
   Basically you would have one (or several) Dagger `component` which could include `subcomponent`. Their lifecycle is handled by [Dagger scope](https://dagger.dev/subcomponents).